# How to keep session in multipage angular application?

Tags: session, angularjs

I am having single page application with user authentication and there is no problem sharing session information there.

However I have part of site where are static pages where I would like just to include session information (logged in user, or login form). How I can share session information between two apps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend creating a service that wraps `localStorage` or other apis to store persistent data. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VAoqzzhZxbpSVKCGPSRC?p=preview) is an example using a `localStorage` implementation.

This implementation is **synchronous** but if I would use `websql` like or even server db then I would refactor it to use [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) to return the storage object.

**Controller**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', [ 'appStorage' ]);

demo.controller('AppStorageController', [ '$scope', 'appStorage',
    function($scope, appStorage) {
      appStorage('MyAppStorage', 'myAppStorage', $scope);
    } ]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppStorageController">
  <p>Local Storage: {{myAppStorage}}</p>
  <p>
    Username: <input type="text" ng-model="myAppStorage.username"></input>
  </p>
  <p>
    Remember me: <input type="checkbox"
      ng-model="myAppStorage.rememberMe"></input>
  </p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('appStorage', []).factory('appStorage',
    [ '$window', function($window) {
      var appStorages = {};
      var api = undefined;

      if ($window.localStorage) {
        api = {
          set : function(name, value) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value));
          },
          get : function(name) {
            var str = $window.localStorage.getItem(name);
            var val = {};
            try {
              val = str ? JSON.parse(str) : {};
            }
            catch (e) {
              console.log('Parse error for localStorage ' + name);
            }
            return val;
          },
          clear : function() {
            $window.localStorage.clear();
          }
        };
      }
      // possibly support other

      if (!api) {
        throw new Error('Could not find suitable storage');
      }

      return function(appName, property, scope) {
        if (appName === undefined) {
          throw new Error('appName is required');
        }

        var appStorage = appStorages[appName];

        var update = function() {
          api.set(appName, appStorage);
        };

        var clear = function() {
          api.clear(appName);
        };

        if (!appStorage) {
          appStorage = api.get(appName);
          appStorages[appName] = appStorage;
          update();
        }

        var bind = function(property, scope) {
          scope[property] = appStorage;
          scope.$watch(property, function() {
            update();
          }, true);
        };

        if (property !== undefined && scope !== undefined) {
          bind(property, scope);
        }

        return {
          get : function(name) {
            return appStorage[name];
          },
          set : function(name, value) {
            appStorage[name] = value;
            update();
          },
          clear : clear
        };
      };
    } ]);
```

Comment: How could I clean a property or a storage app using this `appStorage` service. For example, if I created a `FooStorage` app and placed a `bar` property in it under `$scope` using `appStorage('FooStorage', 'bar', $scope);` then what could I do to clean just the `bar` property and what if I needed to clean the whole `FooStorage`?

Comment: @skip I would add a removeApp method to the api that will call localStorage.removeItem by the name of the app in this case FooStorage. If you want to remove a property then add a remove method that will delete the property in the map then resave the value to localStorage.

Comment: If I have `var fooStore = appStorage('FooStorage', 'bar', $scope);`, should calling `fooStore.clear();` not clear all the data stored in the `fooStore`? I get the the stored data even after I reload the page after calling the `fooStore.clear();`. How could I clear all the data from `fooStore`? Thanks.