# Is there any directive named "ngSession" in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to store data in session so that it will be available across pages. So looking for directive or any other way in angularJS so that this can be achieved?

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515657/how-to-keep-session-in-multipage-angular-application
follow this or take a look at this:http://maffrigby.com/maintaining-session-info-in-angularjs-when-you-refresh-the-page/

Comment: or follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js